# Replace master page menu control

Tags: asp.net

I want to replace the menu control of master page from contentplaceholder when i click on submit button
   what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You just access the control and disable it.
Maybe add a placeholder where you place the new control.

How to access the controls in the master page:

[How To retrieve a control in a Master Page from Content Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088426/how-to-retrive-a-control-in-a-master-page-from-content-page)